# Do I need to catch the Primeape?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

What to do if I don't catch the Primeape that evolved from the Mankey that took my hat? I'm asking because I need it for the P1 championship. Is there another way to pass it? I tried to use Makuhita, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile since I played Ash Grey, but you could catch a wild Mankey (Avaliable on Route 1), evolve it, and try using that for the event.

Comment: You cant go to route 1 after getting to route 6 i think

Comment: I think McLemore meant to do that at the start of the game (good luck, it has an insanely LOW encounter rate) and keep the Mankey on your team until it Levels up to Primeape. Just be warned, though, the highest Level you can catch is 3 and it doesn't Evolve until 28